# How to create a selector for a Button programmatically

Tags: android, button, selector, android-button

How to create a selector programmatically (Kotlin) for an ImageButton with the following requirements.

- Only the background scales by 25% while the image remains the same size while the button is at the `Pressed` state.
- The background colour of the button at the `Pressed` state is different from that of the normal (default) state.
- able to set the background colour programmatically for the button so that the same button can be reused.

Thank you for all the help in advance

Comment: When you say " the background scales by 25%" should the background scale such that it exceeds the width/height of the _ImageButton_ or will it be contained within the view bounds? Is the background a solid color?

Comment: The background is a solid colour and it's within the view bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to recreate the following drawable programmatically:

```
<selector>
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/holo_blue_light" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item>
        <inset android:drawable="@android:color/holo_red_light" android:inset="12.5%" />
    </item>
</selector>
```

This [StateListDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable) uses an [InsetDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/InsetDrawable) to set the background color to something smaller than the view width and height.

In the following layout

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray">

    <View
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_drawable"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

the background behaves as follows:

[image]

The green square is there just to show the true extent of the *ImageButton*.

Here is the code to create the StateListDrawable programmatically and to assign it to the *ImageButton*:

```
val blue = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_light)  
val red = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_light)  
  
// Create the inset drawable that is inset 12.5% on each side. This will be the default state.  
val colorDrawable = ColorDrawable(red)  
val insetDrawable = InsetDrawable(colorDrawable, 0.12f)  
  
// Create the drawable that will be the pressed state background.  
val pressedStateDrawable = ColorDrawable(blue)  
val bg = StateListDrawable()  
bg.addState(intArrayOf(android.R.attr.state_pressed), pressedStateDrawable)  
bg.addState(intArrayOf(), insetDrawable)  
binding.imageButton.background = bg
```

---

---

If you want to animate the background, you can use a [ScaleDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ScaleDrawable) with a [ValueAnimator](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator). Here is some sample code:

```
val baseLevel = 7500
val topLevel = 10000
val animationDuration = 250L
val redColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.holo_red_light)
val colorDrawable = ColorDrawable(redColor)
val blueColor = ContextCompat.getColor(requireContext(), android.R.color.holo_blue_light)
val scaleDrawable = ScaleDrawable(colorDrawable, Gravity.CENTER, 1f, 1f)
scaleDrawable.level = baseLevel
binding.imageButton.background = scaleDrawable
binding.imageButton.setOnClickListener {
    ValueAnimator.ofInt(baseLevel, topLevel).apply {
        duration = animationDuration
        doOnStart {
            (scaleDrawable.drawable as ColorDrawable).color = blueColor
            scaleDrawable.level = baseLevel
        }
        addUpdateListener {
            scaleDrawable.level = it.animatedValue as Int
            binding.imageButton.invalidate()
        }
        doOnEnd {
            (scaleDrawable.drawable as ColorDrawable).color = redColor
            scaleDrawable.level = baseLevel
        }
        start()
    }
}
```

[image]

---

---

A still better way (IMO) is to encapsulate the expanding drawable as a custom drawable.

**ExpandingBackgroundDrawable.kt**

```
class ExpandingBackgroundDrawable(
    matchStates: IntArray,
    activeColor: Int,
    insetPercentage: Float,
    animationDuration: Long
) : Drawable(), Animatable, TimeAnimator.TimeListener {

    private val mMatchStates = matchStates
    private val mInsetPercentage = insetPercentage
    private val mAnimDuration = animationDuration

    private var mRunning = false
    private var mStartTime = 0L
    private val mTimeAnimator: TimeAnimator = TimeAnimator().also {
        it.setTimeListener(this)
    }

    private var mPaint: Paint = Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG).apply {
        color = activeColor
        style = Paint.Style.FILL
    }

    private val mRectMin = RectF()
    private val mRectCurrent = RectF()

    // Notify this Drawable when the View's state changes.
    override fun isStateful() = true

    override fun onStateChange(states: IntArray): Boolean {
        return if (StateSet.stateSetMatches(mMatchStates, states)) {
            start()
            true
        } else {
            false
        }
    }

    override fun onBoundsChange(bounds: Rect) {
        super.onBoundsChange(bounds)
        mRectMin.set(
            0f, 0f, bounds.right - mInsetPercentage * bounds.right * 2,
            bounds.bottom - mInsetPercentage * bounds.bottom * 2
        )
    }

    override fun draw(canvas: Canvas) {
        canvas.withTranslation(
            (bounds.width() - mRectCurrent.right) / 2,
            (bounds.height() - mRectCurrent.bottom) / 2
        ) {
            canvas.drawRect(mRectCurrent, mPaint)
        }
    }

    override fun setAlpha(alpha: Int) {
        mPaint.alpha = alpha
    }

    override fun setColorFilter(colorFilter: ColorFilter?) {
        mPaint.colorFilter = colorFilter
    }

    override fun getOpacity() = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT

    override fun start() {
        if (isRunning) return
        mRunning = true
        mStartTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()
        invalidateSelf()
        mTimeAnimator.duration = mAnimDuration
        mTimeAnimator.start()
    }

    override fun stop() {
        if (!isRunning) return
        mTimeAnimator.cancel()
        mRunning = false
        invalidateSelf()
    }

    override fun isRunning() = mRunning

    override fun onTimeUpdate(animation: TimeAnimator, totalTime: Long, deltaTime: Long) {
        val progress = totalTime.toFloat() / animation.duration
        mRectCurrent.right = mRectMin.right + (bounds.right - mRectMin.right) * progress
        mRectCurrent.bottom = mRectMin.bottom + (bounds.bottom - mRectMin.bottom) * progress
        if (progress >= 1F) {
            stop()
        } else {
            invalidateSelf()
        }
    }

    fun setColor(color: Int) {
        mPaint.color = color
        invalidateSelf()
    }
}
```

The custom drawable would be created as follows:

```
imageButton.background = getBackground(context)

private fun getBackground(view: View): Drawable {
    val context = view.context

    // Create the inset drawable that is inset 12.5% on each side.
    // This will be the default state.
    val red = ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.holo_red_light)
    val colorDrawable = ColorDrawable(red)
    val insetDrawable = InsetDrawable(colorDrawable, 0.125f)

    // Get the expanding background drawable that is the pressed state drawable.
    val expandingStates = intArrayOf(
        android.R.attr.state_pressed,
        android.R.attr.state_accelerated
    )
    val mExpandingBackground = ExpandingBackgroundDrawable(
        expandingStates,
        ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.accent),
        0.125f,
        context.resources.getInteger(android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime).toLong()
    )

    return StateListDrawable().apply {
        addState(expandingStates, mExpandingBackground)
        addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, insetDrawable)
    }
}
```

While the state of the *ImageButton* is "pressed", the background will start as the size of the *InsetDrawable* and expand to the size of the outer square. When the "pressed" state is removed, the drawable will disappear.

Answer (score -1):

try it in your xml code

```
android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
```